# Решение задач. Количество страниц памяти

Tags: c, алгоритм

Здравствуйте, уважаемые коллеги!

Вопрос, может быть, достаточно тривиальный. Есть память EEPROM, размер страницы в ней - 16 байт (см. рисунок). Можно начать запись с любого байта, но за один сеанс записи нельзя вылезти в соседнюю страницу. В связи с этим требуется определить количество страниц памяти, которые подлежат записи. При этом известен номер ячейки, с которой начинается запись, и общее количество записываемых байт. Следует учесть и ту ситуацию, что одно и то же количество информации может занимать разное количество страниц в зависимости от начального адреса (см. рисунок).

Итак, коллеги, можете ли вы предложить маленькую красивую формулу, по которой можно вычислить количество страниц? Мне бы не хотелось использовать циклические алгоритмы. Язык - Си.

Не буду выкладывать свои наработки, скажу только, что моё решение не учитывает последней обозначенной проблемы, результат получается как в нижней части рисунка.

[image: Схема памяти]

Comment: Как то не до конца понятны входные данные. "Номер ячейки" - это ячейка с которой начнется запись на текущей странинце?

Comment: Номер ячейки - порядковый номер (с нуля) от начала всей доступной области.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static inline n_pages (unsigned int addr, unsigned int len) {
    return len ? ((addr + len - 1) >> 4) - (addr >> 4) + 1 : 0;
}
```

вроде так?

(первое выражение -- номер страницы с адресом последнего байта данных (`addr + len - 1` это адрес последнего байта) , второе -- номер страницы с началом данных, соответственно их разница + 1 -- это количество страниц)

Comment: @Abyx, не, кажется нужны (т.к. первое выражение -- номер страницы с адресом последнего байта данных, второе -- начало данных, соответственно их разница + 1 -- это количество страниц)  /  А вот что точно надо, так проверять len != 0. Сейчас поправлю, будем считать, что данные нулевой длины(???) занимают 0 страниц.

Comment: @avp, это интересный подход. Я пытался число байт делить на размер страницы и округлять вверх. Завтра протестирую. Необычно также деление на 16 через сдвиг.

Comment: @maestro, подход просто напрашивается самой формулировкой задачи -- *"найти число страниц..."* --> вычислим номера страниц по адресам начала и конца данных и т.д., ну а вычисление номера страницы не делением на степень двойки, а через сдвиг -- это же просто идиома системного программирования (возникла в те времена, когда компайлеры были совсем тупые, а CPU совсем синхронными).

Comment: Непонятно зачем в о всех (!) ответах фигурирует это куул-хацкерская манера замусоривать код какими-то сдвигами на 4 вместо обыкновенного деления на 16.

Comment: @AnT, дурной пример заразителен  (экономия символов при делителе > 64 :)) (и похоже, что мой ответ самый первый).

Answer (score 2):

http://codepad.org/pfU3A77J

```
inline unsigned page_of_byte(unsigned i)
  {
  return i >> 4;
  }

inline unsigned pages_count(unsigned l, unsigned r)
  {
  return page_of_byte(r) - page_of_byte(l) + 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

До кучи, мой вариант: `pages = ((addr & 0xFUL) + size + 15UL) >> 4 + 1;`

PS: не понятно, как поможет упростить алгоритм записи знание числа страниц, если для записи в первую надо учитывать смещение, а при записи в последнюю остаток.